# javascript sum of two numbers inside an array print index of numbers whoose sum = target

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/12qIWazKzBr1yJGpo1z106euXVJMKMwEa/view?usp=sharing][1]i have to find the index of two numbers whoose sum = target[number given as argument] i have tried to solve this through for loop but i am not getting the indexex correctly as if the first two numbers of array are 1,1 and target is set as two i am getting answer  as [0,0] but i want [0,1]

```
let arr = [1,1,8,9,7,22,6]




var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++)
        if(nums[i] + nums[j]==target){
           
            return [nums.indexOf(nums[i]) , nums.indexOf(nums[j])]
        }

    }
};
console.log(twoSum(arr, 2))
i am expecting output as [0,1]
but i am getting output as [0,0]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1jo7.png
```

Comment: just return i and j..

Comment: Do not use indexof. As first time j value will be 1 and indexOf will return very first occurance of 1 from array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes made:- Just change the return statement of yours**

**Code:-**

```
let arr = [1,1,8,9,7,22,6]
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++)
        if(nums[i] + nums[j]==target){
            return [i,j]
        }

    }
};
console.log(twoSum(arr, 2))
```

**Output:-**

```
node /tmp/fiXkoJ2VkT.js
[ 0, 1 ]
```

**Note let's say you want a sum 9.`[0,2]` and `[1,2]` both sum up to give 9 but the output will be `[0,2]` not `[1,2]` as you are checking for 1st element all cases than 2nd element all cases and so on..**

**Updated section .. {your query}**

[image]

Comment: let arr = [2,5,5,11] for this array if target is 10 its still returning [1,1] how can i fix that

Comment: It working fine on my side.. [1,2] output showing

Comment: its still showing as 1,1 for me i dont know why

Comment: share your screenshot in question..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12qIWazKzBr1yJGpo1z106euXVJMKMwEa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: see my updated section

Comment: what is this condition for `num[i]!==num[j]` in your code..

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf` method returns the first occurrence of a particular value. Since you have `1` in both `0` and `1` indexes, It will only return `0` because it is the first occurrence of `1`.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Just return the `i` and `j` itself.

```
return [i, j];
```

Comment: let arr = [2,5,5,11] for this array if target is 10 its still returning [1,1] how can i fix that

Comment: let arr = [2,5,5,11] for this array if target is 10 its still returning [1,1] how can i fix that

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 8, 9, 7, 22, 6];

function twoSum(arr, target) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === target) console.log([i, j]);
    }
  }
}

twoSum(arr, 2);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).